gitlab CI/CD runners dont do anything
Cant make runner to start a job, but runner is actve and pipeline seems like okey
My runner is on the other server but i connec them via vpn, and ping command tells me that they are connected
GitlabRunner
This is runner config
[[runners]]
  name = "TEEEEST_FOR_NOT_DOCKER"
  url = "http://git.stdpr.ru/"
  id = 46
  token = "5da4690ec2c1d85fdd22a40aabb6f7"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-04-02T14:27:53Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  environment = ["FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD=1"]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/dotnet:v1.42.0-jammy"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0
    allowed_pull_policies = ["always", "if-not-present"]
    allowed_images = ["my.registry.tld:5000/*:*"]
    allowed_services = ["my.registry.tld:5000/*:*"]
  [runners.docker.volume_driver_ops]
    "size" = "20G"

Gitlab CI/CD sees my runner but does nothing
This is my yml file for pipeline
image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/dotnet:v1.42.0-jammy

test:
    script:
    - echo"Hello World"


I`ve tried to start a pipelene, but my job just in pending
job pending in pipeline
